How to add a third argument to a popup_menu() callback function?
So far, I know that you can pass only two arguments to popup callback functions. I am wondering if there is any way to pass a third argument? Shall I rely on some sort of closure or use some "partial" functions like functools.partial() in Python? Or shall I use closures?
Example:
vim9script
var my_fruit = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
var my_animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'snake']

def MyPopupCallback(id: number, idx: number)
   # Here I want to do something depending if 'type' arg passed to MyPopup() is 'animals' or 'fruit'
enddef

def MyPopup(title: string, results: list<string>, type: string)
  popup_menu(results, {
    title: title,
    callback: MyPopupCallback,
  })
enddef

MyPopup('My cuties', my_animals, 'animals')
MyPopup('My food', my_fruit, 'fruit')

I would do something like the following (assuming that MyPopupCallback signature is MyPopupCallback(type: string, id: number, idx: number) and assuming that a partial() function exists):
vim9script
def MyPopup(title: string, results: list<string>, type: string)

  var MyPopupCallbackPartial = MyPopupCallback
  if type == 'animal'
       MyPopupCallbackPartial = partial(MyPopupCallback, 'animal')
  if type == 'fruit'
       MyPopupCallbackPartial = partial(MyPopupCallback, 'fruit')
  endif

  popup_menu(results, {
    title: title,
    callback: MyPopupCallbackPartial,
  })
enddef


may I recommend that you make sure you include vim9script at the top of your blocks, add the vim9script tag to your questions and possibly mention vim9script more prominently in your questions? vim9script is fairly different from the classic vimscript and it's also not available in Neovim which is what a lot of people are using these days, so you might want to be more explicit in that vim9script is what you're asking about. Thanks!

Oh ok. I'll do that. I thought it was clear from the context given the syntax (if it does not look like Lua, nor legacy Vim what else could it be?) but if it helps, sure I can do that.

You were on the right track, you basically need to use function() to create a partial. I modified your example code to come up with this:
vim9script

var my_fruit: list<string> = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
var my_animals: list<string> = ['dog', 'cat', 'snake']

def MyPopupCallback(type: string, id: number, idx: number)
    echomsg type
enddef

def MyPopup(title: string, results: list<string>, type: string)
    var MyPopupCallbackPartial: func
    if type == 'animal'
        MyPopupCallbackPartial = function(MyPopupCallback, ['animal'])
    elseif type == 'fruit'
        MyPopupCallbackPartial = function(MyPopupCallback, ['fruit'])
    else
        echoerr "Invalid type!"
    endif

    popup_menu(results, {
        title: title,
        callback: MyPopupCallbackPartial,
    })
enddef


MyPopup('My cuties', my_animals, 'animal')
MyPopup('My food', my_fruit, 'fruit')


I would use lambda function to dispatch:
vim9script

var my_fruit = ['banana', 'apple', 'orange']
var my_animals = ['dog', 'cat', 'snake']

def MyPopupCallback(type: string, id: number, idx: number)
   # Here I want to do something depending if 'type' arg passed to MyPopup() is 'animals' or 'fruit'
   echow type idx
enddef

def MyPopup(title: string, results: list<string>, type: string)
  popup_menu(results, {
    title: title,
    callback: (id, idx) => {
        MyPopupCallback(type, id, idx)
    },
  })
enddef

# MyPopup('My cuties', my_animals, 'animals')
MyPopup('My food', my_fruit, 'fruit')

